# How to see the HTML code of a signature from an email?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-signature

Can I download or otherwise see the code of a signature HTML file from an email in Outlook?

Answer (score 4):

In Outlook 2010 :

- Open the mail
- Clic on the "other actions" button (next to the "move" button")
- Clic on "other actions" in the menu
- Clic on "see the source"

You will then see here the html code of the message, and the signature.

Answer (score 0):

#### In Office 365 Outlook

Right click on mail preview or in opened mail, and select View Source in drop down menu.